# iOS 9 : how to make the content view of a scroll bar bottom stick to the scrollview bottom?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView whose backgroundColor is UIColor.clearColor().
That scroll view's content view has background color red and take advantage of the standard bouncing feature.

But when I scroll it upwards, when the scroll exceeds the contentSize height, the underlying views appears (reminding you the scroll background being clear color). See the image:

[image]

My code is quite standard:

```
    scrollView.delegate           = self
    scrollView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.clearColor()
    scrollView.contentSize        = view.frame.size

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Comment: you haven't said why the scroll is transparent and what you actually want to happen, or how you tried to make that thing happen

Comment: It's a design request: we need to see thru at the top-end of the content view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple and just add another view behind the scroll view at the bottom of the screen, probably about half the height of the view, and the same colour as the background. So, when you scroll the content up you just see through to that view instead of the content behind.

You could turn bouncing on and off depending on the scroll direction but you'd get little UI glitches. You could add a delegate for the scroll gesture recogniser and use `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` but you could end up with similar UI issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIView` into your `scrollView` with the same color as your content background color. Set its `frame` so its outside the `scrollView.contentSize` (ie: `y < 0` at the top, `y > contentSize.height` at the bottom). Make it big enough to cover the bounce gap.